# django ModelForm override field has no effect

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a `ForeignKey` field in a model of mine, and I'm using `ModelForm` with it to generate the HTML. The thing is, I want to add an `Other` option as well - I plan to add JavaScript with it so that a textbook appears when that's selected.

I'm looking at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets, and started off with trying something like

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.DateField()
    .
    .
    .
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    affiliation = models.ForeignKey('Affiliation')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class EventForm(ModelForm):
    cost = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

`cost` should become a text field instead of char field, so the output should be `textarea` instead of `input[type=text]`. This doesn't change, however, no errors are printed, and nothing really happens. I was hoping to proceed by doing

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    affiliations = list(Affiliation.objects.all()).append('Other')
    affiliation = forms.CharField(choices=affiliations)
    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

I'm using django-nonrel on GAE if it helps, but this isn't really an issue with the Model (or so I think...) so I don't think it should change anything. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used django-nonrel, so take this tip with a grain of salt (YMMV).

In your `EventForm` definition, you're setting `cost` to be a `model.TextField` - but you actually want it to be a `forms.CharField`, with a textarea widget.

Comment: forms.TextField doesn't exist, its' a CharField with textarea input :)

Comment: Whoops - looks like I was looking at the wrong column on http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types - updated, thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: thanks, I guess I'm thrown off by how it let me set that without complaining. ): mean.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that EventForm is overriding cost with a `models.TextField()` when it should be `forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())`

Answer (score 0):

Can a CharField have choices? Django docs show a 'ChoiceField' which would seem to be what you want...

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#charfield